# Is it possible for Google Vision object_localization to search for a specific Google Grpah object?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I'm trying to use Google's machine vision API to search for a specific occurrence of a Google Graph object.  Is this part of the API?  I can't find anything in the documentation.  Thanks!

Specifically:

"@id": "kg:/m/06_fw"

Answer (score 0):

Detection of Google Graph Objects cannot be done directly using the Vision API. 
With Vision API the identification is based on what are called MID's, a machine-generated identifier. These correspond to label's in the Google Knowledge Graph entry. For information on inspecting mid values you should refer to this document [Google Knowledge Graph Search API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/?_ga=2.201977561.91864304.1581329881-223010882.1580736364&_gac=1.144820864.1581504403.EAIaIQobChMIkfrK--rL5wIVCUTTCh1y4AYuEAAYASAAEgKzFvD_BwE). As per the documentation;

> The Knowledge Graph Search API returns only individual matching entities, rather than graphs of interconnected entities. If you need the latter, we recommend using data dumps from [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page) instead

Comment: Thank you.  I will try to make my own.